# One line HTTPS server

Tags: http, https

There are quite a few one line HTTP servers available e.g.

Python

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Ruby

```
ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000
```

etc.

Are there any 1 line HTTPS servers? If they generate their own self signed certificates, even better. A small number of lines will work too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ruby [WEBrick documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html) has a [section on HTTPS](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html#module-WEBrick-label-HTTPS). I needed to add `DocumentRoot` and `.start` and arrived at this:

```
ruby -r webrick/https -e '
  WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
    Port: 8000, DocumentRoot: ".",
    SSLEnable: true, SSLCertName: [%w[CN localhost]]).start'
```

I tested with Ruby 2.1.2.

Answer (score 6):

[Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io) does this well.

Install with

```
npm i -g browser-sync
```

Serve the contents of the current directory with

```
browser-sync start -s --https
```

No setup required. See the [docs](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line) for other features.

Comment: handy options to keep it minimal: `--no-ui` disables the Web UI, `--no-open` if you don't want a new window/tab opening

Answer (score 2):

[Hunchentoot](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/) could be used for this purpose. The one line is rather long, but not impossibly so. You will need to provide the certificate and key from files, though.

```
sbcl --eval '(progn
  (and nil #.(require "hunchentoot")) 
  (setq hunchentoot:*dispatch-table* 
        (list (hunchentoot:create-folder-dispatcher-and-handler "/" "'`pwd`/'"))) 
  (hunchentoot:start (make-instance (quote hunchentoot:easy-ssl-acceptor) 
                                    :port 8443
                                    :ssl-privatekey-file "../cert.key"
                                    :ssl-certificate-file "../cert.crt")))'
```

The command above has been split on multiple lines for readability; it can be entered as a single line as well.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the following chrome error:
*Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key*
You need to provide a set of ciphers that are strong enough to satisfy chrome requirements, e.g.:

```
 -cipher kRSA+RSA
```

The following works for me:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 443 -cipher kRSA+RSA
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to pretty simple with OpenSSL's s_server utility. I've just used this to help test out a load-balancer configuration before the real backend was ready (not to serve content per-se). The first line creates a self-signed certificate.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -x509 -subj '/CN=name-you-want.example.com' -days 3650 -out server.cert -keyout server.key
openssl s_server -accept 7781 -cert server.cert -key server.key -WWW
```

See the manual page for s_server for more info.

Comment: Great. Chrome doesn't approve of the encryption, though: "Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key"

Answer (score 1):

If you want both an HTTP and HTTPS listener for testing (and keep it running until a server is restarted):

```bash
#Start an HTTP server with directory browsing
mkdir /tmp/www
cd  /tmp/www; touch "$(hostname).txt"
sudo nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 > simplehttpserver.out &

#Start an HTTPS listener with some debug responses (I wonder if you can pipe to the HTTP server)
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout /tmp/key.pem -out /tmp/cert.pem -days 365 #Create self signed key. Only need this once and it will ask a few questions
sudo nohup openssl s_server -key /tmp/key.pem -cert /tmp/cert.pem -accept 443 -cipher kRSA+RSA -www > openssl.out &
```

Answer (score 1):

Download [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/download)

Allow executable permissions

```
chmod +x caddy
```

Run a caddy server

```
./caddy file-server --domain localhost --browse
```

Browse https://localhost

Answer (score 0):

One more option that more people might find compelling, as it uses infrastructure that many devs will already have in place, is:

```
npx https-localhost
```

The https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-localhost package depends on having npm installed, of course, and takes care of generating the required certificate and trusting it locally.

To serve an arbitrary path on an arbitrary port, you might do something like:

```
PORT=10000 npx https-localhost ~/my-experiment
```